# How to take a picture with raspberry pi camera module and display it from an android app

Tags: android, image, sockets, raspberry-pi, android-camera

I have an android app that opens a socket with my raspberry and sends data. This works fine and I'm able to send whatever between the devices.

However, I would like to send a command of some sort from my android telling the raspberry to take a picture and then send it back to my android which displays the image. It's quite possible that this can be managed fairly simple but I've really tried and also searched all over the web with no luck.

Any ideas? All answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to do is set the raspi as a server using a loop that repeatedly listens for data on the socket, preferably a command using a protocol that you invent, and calling other functions based on the received command.

For instance, your client sends the text 'TAKE_PIC' to the raspi. The raspi receives the 'TAKE_PIC' command, calls a function(s) to take a picture, and send back that picture back to the client which listens for a response after sending a command.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do! The thing is I have a both a client and a server which already can communicate and wait for each other. My problem is I have no idea how to write the methods which makes the raspi take a picture and then send it back.. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Oliver It sounds like perhaps you're searching for too specific of a problem. Break this into chunks. There are numerous tutorials on developing on a RasPi and interfacing with attached peripherals. There is even a [StackExchange community just for Raspberry Pi.](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Yes I understand it sounds a bit to specific. I was just hoping there was a really simple solution that made it possible to access the rpi's camera module from your android or something. Guess I will have to start from scratch and go through some tutorials. Thanks guys!